# Rxjs pipe function with multiple filter() and switchMap() operators in the chain

Tags: angular, rxjs-pipeable-operators, rxjs-filter

I'm in the midst of refactoring some old rxjs code which was written poorly and therefore has some race conditions.

So I'd like to use a chain of **filter() operators** based on various conditions; however I need it to visit EVERY filter operator along this chain. i.e. If Condition1 is true, execute the next switchMap() - otherwise just follow down to the next filter(). Apply the same logic to Condition2..Condition4.

Also, my **selectedNode** needs to be emitted down the chain because the **getChildNodes()** function fetches additional child nodes and pushes them onto **selectedNode**.

Right now **it just bails on when it encounters the first FALSY condition** - so naturally the rest of the filters will never get checked.

How do I make it such that if will execute as an old IF...THEN statement on each condition?

Here's what I have so far:

```js
    constructor(private readonly configSvc: ConfigService) {
        this.model$
            .pipe(
                filter((selectedNode) => !!selectedNode),

                // if condition1 passes, get child nodes of current node.
                filter((selectedNode) => myCondition1),
                switchMap((selNode) => this.getChildNodes(selNode, NodeType.Type1)),

                // if condition2 passes..
                filter((selectedNode) => myCondition2),
                switchMap((selNode) => this.getChildNodes(selNode, NodeType.Type2)),

                // if condition3 passes..
                filter((selectedNode) => myCondition3),
                switchMap((selNode) => this.getChildNodes(selNode, NodeType.Type3)),

                // if condition4 passes, get child nodes...
                filter((selectedNode) => myCondition4),
                switchMap((selNode) => this.getChildNodes(selNode, NodeType.Type4)),

                takeUntil(this.onDestroy),
            )
            .subscribe({
                next: (selectedNode: SelectedNode) => { // init the Network tree and notify listeners
                    this.initNetwork(selectedNode);
                    this.configNodesReadySource.next(selectedNode);
                },
            });
    }
```

or perhaps subscribing to mult observables, an an alt idea:

```js
const condition1$ = this.model$.pipe(filter((node) => condition1), switchMap(...);
const condition2$ = this.model$.pipe(filter(...), switchMap(...);
const condition3$ = this.model$.pipe(filter(...), switchMap(...);
const condition4$ = this.model$.pipe(filter(...), switchMap(...);

forkJoin(...).subsribe(...); // join condition1 thru 4 to get final result ???
```

However, it seems I have the same problem or similar. I NEVER reach the subscribe.

Comment: Not sure which version of RxJS you're using, but I believe [iif](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/conditional/iif) could do the trick.

Comment: 6.6.3 and angular 13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [concatMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/concatMap) to achieve cascading as described

```
this.model$
.pipe(
    filter((selectedNode) => !!selectedNode),
    concatMap(selectedNode => myCondition1 ? this.getChildNodes(selectedNode, NodeType.Type1) : of(selectedNode)),
    concatMap(selectedNode => myCondition2 ? this.getChildNodes(selectedNode, NodeType.Type2) : of(selectedNode)),
    concatMap(selectedNode => myCondition3 ? this.getChildNodes(selectedNode, NodeType.Type3) : of(selectedNode)),
    concatMap(selectedNode => myCondition4 ? this.getChildNodes(selectedNode, NodeType.Type4) : of(selectedNode)),
    takeUntil(this.onDestroy),
)
.subscribe({
    next: (selectedNode: SelectedNode) => { // init the Network tree and notify listeners
        this.initNetwork(selectedNode);
        this.configNodesReadySource.next(selectedNode);
    },
});
```

Comment: but my **selectedNode** needs to be emitted down the chain because the **getChildNodes()** function fetches additional child nodes and pushes them onto **selectedNode**, then returns an Observable.

Comment: @bob.mazzo Please check my new edit

Comment: Good idea, and this might work for me. However I would need of(selectedNode) in order to emit that as an Observable to the next operator in the chain.

Comment: Yep, that was definitely a mistake in my answer, should have had `of(selectedNode)` instead